# remove `CRLF` when after `CRLF` is not a number

Tags: regex, newline, notepad++

I have a file with this structure:

```
23141601       aaaa CRLF
23141602       bbbb CRLF
23141603       cccc CRLF
23141604       dddd CRLF
23141605       eeee CRLF
23141700       ffff CRLF
fffff CRLF //problem here
23141701       gggg CRLF
```

And i need to break each line by the initial number. Remove this **CRLF** for example

```
23141700       ffff CRLF 
fffff
```

The file has 30.000 lines, it is possible remove `CRLF` when after `CRLF` is not a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible (with Notepad++ Version >= 6.0)

Search for

```
\r\n(?!\d)
```

and replace with nothing

- `Search mode = Regular Expression`.

`(?!\d)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), this assertion is true if there is no digit following the pattern `\r\n`.